# Search for a way to sustain lightning electricity

Tags: energy, electricity, lightning

Is it possible to **sustain lightning electricity** through lightning rods?

Comment: What do you mean by "sustain"?

Comment: I mean to preserve

Comment: You mean capture the energy?

Answer (score 1):

Lightning occurs when two conditions are met: opposite charge buildup between two regions (often the ground and a cloud), and the existence of an insulating material between them (the atmosphere).  If there was no insulating medium, it would be easier for charges to "leak" between the two regions and there would never be a significant charge buildup that leads to the large potential differences which generate lightning.

Lightning is visible when a path through the atmosphere is ionized and charges suddenly flow/are conducted along this path, accelerating and thus releasing light.

If these prerequisites are in place for lightning to be created, then it will occur in a stepwise manner characterized by a buildup of charge and a sudden release once the energy threshold for ionizing the air is reached. Therefore, lightning will only occur in sudden bursts and cannot be sustained, since no charge can flow if there isn't enough energy to ionize a path through the air.  If the ionization energy of the atmosphere was smaller (i.e. it was composed of a different mixture of gases), then the charge-buildup required for lightning to form would be lower, but as a result, lightning flashes would be dimmer and smaller, though more frequent.

Essentially, you can't sustain lightning because once you've drained off some of the charge buildup, the potential difference between the cloud and the ground becomes too low to ionize a conductive path through the atmosphere and the charge stope flowing.